# sliding box in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, position, css-position

i want my site to have sliding box like [this site]

I can do this by having a `text widget` and setting the `position` attribute to `fixed`.But it will not slide down.Do I have to use Javascript here?
Thanks
here is my code

```
    <div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <ul class="xoxo">

<li id="text-4" class="widget-container widget_text">           <div class="textwidget"><table border="0">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="text-align: center">
                    <a href="http://nwfighting.com/files/2013/01/jiujitsuofferclean.png">
                        <img class="alignright size-full wp-image-4449" title="jiujitsuoffer" src="http://nwfighting.com/files/2013/01/jiujitsuofferclean.png" alt="" width="200" height="165" />
                    </a>
                </p>
<p style="text-align: center"></p>
                <p style="text-align: center">
                    <span style="font-size: 18px;color: #002aff">
                        <strong>
                            And Get a 2nd Video "Jiu Jitsu Fitness <BR>Secrets!"
                        </strong>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p style="text-align: center">
                    <strong>
                        <span style="font-size: 16px">
                            And Ask About Our 30 Days Free Offer!
                        </span>
                    </strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                        <p>
                  <p style="text-align: center">
                    <strong>
                        <span style="font-size: 18px">
                            -Enter Your Info Here to Get Your Free Video-
                        </span>
                    </strong>   
                </p>
</p>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cn112.infusionsoft.com/app/form/iframe/323c5df08af18d52623818df2e915c02"></script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
        </li>           </ul>
        </div><!-- #primary .widget-area -->
```

Comment: Yes, you need JS to achieve the slide effect upon page scroll. You haven't explained why {position: fixed} isn't working, so it's hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: @isherwood please see the site i sent you they didn't used fixed..

Comment: @isherwood when I write "fixed" it doesn't even show the image and textboxes..I have uypdte the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site actually uses a plugin that make use of Javascript.You can simply use this Script and get it done

```
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/strx-magic-floating-sidebar-maker/
```

Hope this would help

Comment: @user1765876 We are here to assist you.